Give an explicit isomorphism between $C^2$ and the set of solutions for the linear system over $R$
Give an explicit isomorphism between $C^2$ and the set of solutions for the linear system (over $R$)
$w + ix − 2y = 1 + i$
$−w + x + 3iz = 2$
The final solution I got is $\begin{bmatrix}x+3i-2 \\x  \\ (1+i)x + (3i)z + 5 + i \\ z\end{bmatrix}$
V = span of solution set
I said $T: C^2 \rightarrow V$ is not linear because it fails the additive property($T(a+b) = T(a) + T(b)$). Thus, an Isomorphism does not exist. My book tells me this is wrong. What am I missing?

Hi! I'd like to ask what your book says explicitly about this. Also, are we sure this is an isomorphism of vector spaces that your book is looking for? The solution set seems to span an affine space, not a vector space.
